Issue with AWS Lambda and EventBridge - Schedule not working as expected
I am facing an issue while configuring AWS Lambda with EventBridge. I set up the scheduling, but when I create the schedule, it gets executed immediately upon creation and does not follow the intended schedule.
Here is the code I am using:
import { CreateItemBody } from '../interfaces/bodyRequest';
import { eventBridgeParamsRequest } from '../interfaces/createEvent';

const eventBridgeClient = new EventBridgeClient({region: "us-east-2"});

export const configureItemSchedule = async (event: CreateItemBody): Promise<PutEventsCommandOutput> => {
  const date = new Date();
  const addThirtySeconds = date.setTime(date.getTime() + 30000)
  const eventParams: eventBridgeParamsRequest = {
    time: new Date(addThirtySeconds),
    source: "my.apisource",
    detailType: "create_event",
    eventBusName: "default",
    Detail: JSON.stringify(event)
  }
  console.log(eventParams);
  const createEvent = await createItemSchedule(eventParams);
  return createEvent;
};

const createItemSchedule = async (parameter: eventBridgeParamsRequest): Promise<PutEventsCommandOutput> => {
  const eventParams: PutEventsCommandInput = {
    Entries: [
      {
        Time: parameter.time,
        Source: parameter.source,
        EventBusName: parameter.eventBusName, 
        DetailType: parameter.detailType,
        Detail: parameter.Detail
      },
    ],
  };
  try {
    const command = new PutEventsCommand(eventParams)
    const response = await eventBridgeClient.send(command);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e as string);
  }
};

What could be wrong? How can I ensure that the event is scheduled for the correct time and not executed immediately?
Any help is appreciated!
I created EventBridge manually and I am experiencing this issue

Your code creates an event that gets sent to EventBridge and therefore triggers your rule immediately, since your rule reacts to events. The Time parameter that you configured is just an information about when the event occured, it will not schedule the event.
If you want to trigger rules on a schedule, you can create rules that run on a schedule using either a cron or a rate expression.
